# How can I save multiple (checkboxes) values in a configuration entity?

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have a standard config entity in Drupal 8.
I'm trying to save multiple values in the form of checkboxes.

The form itself looks like this:
[image]

As you can see it's nothing too special about it.

If I try to save it, the following exception occurs:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The configuration property user_role.anonymous doesn't exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get() (line 74 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php).


Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->castValue('user_role.anonymous', 'anonymous') (Line: 211)
Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->castValue('user_role', Array) (Line: 212)
Drupal\Core\Config\Config->save() (Line: 280)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->doSave('pl_n_6467f20669ddf097337c47aab87e3c', Object) (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 259)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line: 364)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 637)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->save() (Line: 130)
Drupal\pl_notifications\Form\PLNotificationsConfigurationForm->save(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 585)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('p_l_notifications_configuration_add_form', Array, Object) (Line: 314)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('p_l_notifications_configuration_add_form', Object) (Line: 74)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 144)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 64)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 656)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Which makes perfect sense since I haven't defined that field in the `ConfigEntityType`.

However, I can't define it since there may be other roles added later on or rather some other roles removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Config (schema) defines two basic types of complex/array definitions.

Mapping:
When you have limited, known set of keys, each with a specific type, e.g. a few strings, integers, booleans and so on.

Sequence:
When you have a unlimited list of values that all have the same type but with unknown or numeric keys. Each element must have the same type. The top level in a config entity and simple config is always a mapping (the type there is a config_object or config_entity or so, but those all extend from mapping)

In your example, you would define the user roles as type sequence in config schema, and as a standard php array in your config entity class.

You can also combine this in any way you can imagine, you have a mapping, one key is a list, each element is a mapping, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody has this problem too.

I ended up serializing the values and saving them as a single field.

I don't know if that is the best approach for it but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same situation with a similar error. The correct resolution for this problem is, that you have to **create a config/schema/YOURMODULE.schema.yml file for (especially!) multi-value settings first**.

Drupal will otherwise fall back to a "wrong" way of storing these settings if it doesn't know how to handle them. Other scalar settings seem to be handled with a better fallback if a schema file doesn't (yet) exist.

Typically I created the schema file after I had successfully implemented the module, that's not possible in this case.

Here's my code example for a filter with a "checkboxes" setting:

```
@Filter(
 *   id = "cookie_content_blocker_extras_element_filter",
 *   title = @Translation("Cookie content blocker filter: Wrap elements automatically"),
 *   description = @Translation("Place this filter before 'Cookie content blocker filter'. Wraps selected HTML elements with external content like iframes, embed, object, link, img in <cookiecontentblocker> automatically."),
 *   type = Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_MARKUP_LANGUAGE,
 *   settings = {
 *     "handle_dom_elements" = {},
 *     "handle_dom_elements_exclude_classes" = "no-cookie-content-blocker",
 *     "src_allowed_local" = 1,
 *     "src_allowed_whitelist" = "",
 *   },
 * )
```

*/config/schema/cookie_content_blocker_extras_element_filter.schema.yml*:

```
filter_settings.cookie_content_blocker_extras_element_filter:
  type: filter
  label: 'Cookie content blocker element filter'
  mapping:
    handle_dom_elements:
      type: sequence
      label: 'HTML element types to auto-block'
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'HTML element type'
    handle_dom_elements_exclude_classes:
      type: string
      label: 'Exclude elements by class'
    src_allowed_whitelist:
      type: string
      label: 'Whitelist external sources (Domains)'
    src_allowed_local:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Whitelist local source'
```

After clearing the cache with this schema.yml the error is gone. Horrible story :D